# How to reduce the length of very long strings?

Tags: php, css, string

I have some text which occasionally contains very long strings of characters, which is breaking my CSS.

This is an example:

http://iapps.smartphonesoft.com/php/software_details.php?id=358281487

whereas this one is fine

http://iapps.smartphonesoft.com/php/software_details.php?id=380894729

Is it possible to strip the very long line of *s in the above example down to a manageable length?

The extra complication is that is not always *s that cause the issue, ie in this example it is the = string which is causing the issue.

http://iapps.smartphonesoft.com/php/software_details.php?id=371255483

So I want to write PHP which carries out the function if a single 'word' within $description is >= 30 chars long, shrink it down to 30 chars.

All the text is kept within the variable $description

regards,

Greg

Comment: This isn't PHP5 specific, please tag correctly. http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php (might want to accept some answers as well)

Comment: I accepted an answer about 10hours before this comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, browsers won't wrap an extremely long word. You can override this behavior and always wrap, even if you need to break a word, with CSS (no PHP required!)

The property is `word-wrap: break-word;` and works in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

you can explode string to array of words,
then check strlen of every word not > 30

like

```
$words = explode(" ", $string);
foreach($words as $k=>$word){
   if(strlen($word) >= 30)
      $words[$k] = substr($word,0,30) ;
}
```

after that return array to one string
with

```
join(' ' ,$words);
```

Comment: And concat with <br/> in the end of each line.

Comment: The problem with this is that, (at least with normal proportional fonts) different characters have different width. As line lengths aren't all that long, you can't rely on the average character width to even out the overall line length. This is why wrapping based on number of characters isn't all that good.